# Why cant I pass images from a key:value pair to a Reactjs function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, bootstrap-5, key-value

```
const Heros = [
  {
    id : 1,
    name : 'Brandon Caserta',
    img : '',
    alt : '',
    age : '21',
    story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
    link : 'ahref here',
    dod : 'DOD June 25, 2018',
    branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    name : 'Macoy Hicks',
    img : '../assets/honorwall/MacoyHicks.png',
    alt : '',
    age : '20',
    story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
    link : 'https://www.navytimes.com/news/your-navy/2021/09/30/how-a-military-jail-failed-to-protect-a-suicidal-sailor-from-himself/',
    dod : 'DOD Feb. 11, 2019',
    branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
    id : 3,
    name : 'Nicole Burnham',
    img : '../assets/honorwall/Nicole-Burnham.jpg',
    alt : '',
    age : '21',
    story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
    link : 'https://popularmilitary.com/soldier-commits-suicide-army-wives-bullied-told-die/',
    dod : 'DOD Jan. 26, 2018',
    branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
    id : 4,
    name : 'Sealth N. Shepard',
    img : '../assets/honorwall/Sealth-N-Shepherd.jpg',
    alt : '',
    age : '22',
    story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
    link : 'ahref here',
    dod : 'DOD Dec. 25, 2019',
    branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
    id : 5,
    name : 'Sean Cloutier',
    img : '../assets/honorwall/Sean-Cloutier.jpg',
    alt : '',
    age : '23',
    story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
    link : 'https://www.concordmonitor.com/Memorial-Day-Mental-Health-Sean-Cloutier-40540089',
    dod : 'DOD May 19, 2012',
    branch : 'US Army'
  },
  {
    id : 6,
    name : 'Kellen Watelet',
    img : '../assets/honorwall/Kellen-Watelet.jpg',
    alt : '',
    age : '22',
    story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
    link : 'ahref here',
    dod : 'DOD Jan. 6, 2020',
    branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
    id : 7,
    name : 'Timothy Defoix Stalter',
    img : '../assets/honorwall/Timothy-Defoix-Stalter.jpg',
    alt : '',
    age : '28',
    story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
    link : 'https://save22.vet/remembrance_wall/timothy-stalter/',
    dod : 'DOD Feb. 4, 2013',
    branch : 'US Army'
  },
  {
    id : 8,
    name : 'Jacob M Gray',
    img : '../assets/honorwall/Jacob-M-Gray.jpg',
    alt : '',
    age : '29',
    story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
    link : 'ahref here',
    dod : 'DOD June 4, 2015',
    branch : 'US Marine Corps'
  },
  {
    id : 9,
    name : 'Sidney (Alex) Jones',
    img : '../assets/honorwall/Sidney-Alex-Jones.jpg',
    alt : '',
    age : '18',
    story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
    link : 'ahref here',
    dod : 'DOD Oct. 22, 2019',
    branch : 'US Marine Corps'
  },
  {
      id : 10,
      name : 'Johnny Carroll',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Johnny-Carroll.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '24',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD April 1, 2013',
      branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
      id : 11,
      name : 'Justin Pugh',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Justin-Pugh.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '28',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD Dec. 25, 2008',
      branch : 'US Marine Corps'
  },
  {
      id : 12,
      name : 'Quinn Teeter',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Quinn-Teeter.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '22',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'https://www.newsweek.com/three-us-navy-sailors-died-last-week-despite-pentagon-prevention-efforts-theres-something-bigger-1468139',
      dod : 'DOD Oct. 22, 2019',
      branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
      id : 13,
      name : 'Nathan Anderson-Harkreader',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Nathan-Anderson-Harkreader.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '18',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD April 6, 2020',
      branch : 'US Army'
  },
  {
      id : 14,
      name : 'Keith F. Lewis',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Keith-F-Lewis.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '31',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD Dec. 20, 2020',
      branch : 'US Army'
  },
  {
      id : 15,
      name : 'David "Max" Walker II',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/David-Max-Walker-II.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '20',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'https://www.columbiadailyherald.com/story/news/2013/07/18/liquor-license-on-hold-for/65040156007/',
      dod : 'DOD July 31, 2012',
      branch : 'US Air Force'
  },
  {
      id : 16,
      name : 'Joshua Reinwasser',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Joshua-Reinwasser.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '23',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'https://www.wptv.com/news/region-st-lucie-county/port-st-lucie/gold-star-family-receives-new-home-in-port-st-lucie',
      dod : 'DOD Nov. 11, 2018',
      branch : 'US Air Force'
  },
  {
      id : 17,
      name : 'Justin P. Mangus',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Justin-P-Mangus.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '24',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'https://www.wkbn.com/news/local-news/oregon-veterans-stop-in-the-valley-to-honor-fallen-service-member/',
      dod : 'DOD May 24, 2020',
      branch : 'US Army'
  },
  {
      id : 18,
      name : 'Jake Thomas Williams',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Jake-Thomas.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '24',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD August 19, 2020',
      branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
      id : 19,
      name : 'Marcus Wood',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Marcus-Woods.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '21',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD Feb. 27, 2017',
      branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
      id : 20,
      name : 'Nicholas J. Manor',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Nicholas-J-Manor.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '18',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD Oct. 30, 2017',
      branch : 'US Army'
  },
  {
      id : 21,
      name : 'Brian Morgen Brockway',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Brian-Morgen-Brockway.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '24',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD June 7, 2021',
      branch : 'US Army'
  },
  {
      id : 22,
      name : 'Justin Arellano',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Justin-Arellano.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '18',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD Sept. 22, 2018',
      branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
      id : 23,
      name : 'Adam C. Duvall',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Adam-C-Duvall.jpg',
      alt : 'Adam C. Duvall in uniform',
      age : 'unknown',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD Oct. 20, 2019',
      branch : 'US Navy'
  },
  {
      id : 24,
      name : 'Richard Noyola',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Richard-Noyola.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '21',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD Oct. 8, 2006',
      branch : 'US Marine Corps'
  },
  {
      id : 25,
      name : 'Rylee Williams',
      img : '../assets/honorwall/Rylee-Williams.jpg',
      alt : '',
      age : '23',
      story : 'Ipsum commodo labore anim mollit enim aliquip veniam Lorem aute velit nisi consequat occaecat',
      link : 'ahref here',
      dod : 'DOD Dec. 8, 2021',
      branch : 'US Navy'
  }
];

export default Heros;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap';
import Heros from '../contexts/Heros';
import './styles.css'

function HonorWall() {
 
  return (
   <div class="row">
     { Heros && Heros.map((Heros) =>
       <div class="col-md-4" key={Heros.id}>
         <div classname="honor-card" class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded text-center" >
           <picture>
            <source type='image/jpg+png' />
            <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src={`"path to image" ${Heros.img}`} alt={Heros.alt} />
           </picture>
            <div class="card-body">
             <h5 class="card-title">{Heros.name}</h5>
             <p class="card-text">{Heros.story}</p>
            <div href="" class="btn btn-primary">Read Their Story</div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    )}
  </div>

export default HonorWall;
```

So im stuck like chuck atm. I've tried everything I can think of but cant for the life of me figure this out. Everything else shows as intended BUT my imgs. I tried looking at the bootstrap docs but didnt find anything that I could use. Am I not passing my key:value pair correctly? I wouldnt think its wrong if everything is working. But when I checked inside my Heros object
    `img : '../assets/honorwall/Rylee-Williams.jpg '`   
for example, I hovered my mouse and it pulls up that my `img` is a string. I would assume that I would have to be a string at first. Can someone help me understand this?

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgHyH.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing Heros.map((Heros)... to Heros.map((Hero)... and your don't need "path to image" in src

Comment: Import your Image instead of using the path.make sure all the images are present and your first object hasn`t any image

Comment: Originally I had src={Heros.img} then I found some info that said to use 'path to image'. I left it like that because I was tired of trying to figure it out. It doesnt work if I used Heros.map((Hero), or Heros.map((item) or whatever props I put.

Comment: So I was able to import 1 photo at a time. But couldnt do map on the photos. That really sucks, I guess ill have to manually input it until I can figure it out later. Im welcome to anyone having any other ideas though.. Thanks again!